# How do I remove words in a .txt file that have no vowel in it?

Tags: python

I'm using python on **repl.it** and I'm very new to coding, and I've tried this but I think this just removes the vowels of the filenames:

```
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    for x in filename.lower():
        if x in vowels:
        newstr = newstr.replace(x,"")
    return newstr
```

Comment: You are iterating over the *filename* not on file object

Comment: use `f = open(filename, 'r').read()` instead of `f = open(filename, 'r')`

Comment: @GhostOps instead its better if he keeps the f object initialization line as it is, and stores the file contents separately so that he can close the f connection later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are iterating over the filename variable, while infact you need to iterate over the contents of the file.

So first of all you will need to read the file like so to fetch the contents -:

```
file_content = f.read()
```

Here we call the read method of the file object f, inorder to read the file and we store the returned value in file_content.

Now we can iterate over this like so -:

```
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
newstr = file_content # Initially new str is same as old str
for x in file_content.lower() : # looping over the smallcase form of the file_content
    if x in vowels:
        # If char in vowels then its replaced by a '' str.
        newstr = newstr.replace(x, '')
```

Also there was a indentation mistake in your if statement within your loop, so that also has to be fixed to prevent errors or wrong outputs.

And finally the newstr you were using should be initialized before the loop to equal the file_content, it just prevents errors where you reference the variable before assignment.

**EDIT**: Also, its always suggested that after you have used your file object to read stuff you close the file object connection with this line -:

```
f.close()
```

This again makes sure that file object does not remain open, since then it would not let you access the file from other sources since it remained open.

So the final code of yours becomes -:

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
newstr = file_content # Initially new str is same as old str
for x in file_content.lower() : # looping over the smallcase form of the file_content
    if x in vowels:
        # If char in vowels then its replaced by a '' str.
        newstr = newstr.replace(x, '')
f.close()
return newstr
```

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed iterating on the letters in the filename. This should do it to remove the vowels of a file its content:

```
import re

def replace_vowels(filename):
    txt = open(filename, 'r').read()
    newstr = re.sub(r'[aeiouAEIOU]', '', txt)
    return(newstr)

replace_vowels('lorem.txt')
```

[image: Lorem example]